# Python: replacing a variable in a looping list

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to go through a list and print out the list using a secondary list of variables.

The problem is that the variables in the list are getting assigned and set, but are not getting printed out properly. This feels like something really simple but I've been stumped for a day or so on it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
side = ""
sideLong = ""
sideShort = ""
sideList = ["Right", "Left"]


jointRemapList =[
    ["Char_Hips", "Root_M"],
    ["Char_" + sideLong + "Finger1", "IndexFinger1_" + sideShort],
    ["Char_" + sideLong + "Finger2", "IndexFinger2_" + sideShort]
    ]

for side in sideList:
    sideLong = side
    sideShort = side[0]

    for jointPair in jointRemapList:

        print sideLong, sideShort, jointPair
```

Expected output would be:

```
Left L ['Char_Hips', 'Root_M']
Left L ['Char_LeftFinger1', 'IndexFinger1_L']
Left L ['Char_LeftFinger2', 'IndexFinger2_L']
Right R ['Char_Hips', 'Root_M']
Right R ['Char_RightFinger1', 'IndexFinger1_R']
Right R ['Char_RightFinger2', 'IndexFinger2_R']
```

Comment: Python doesn't keep pointers to variables this way. `"foo" + bar` is not the string "foo" with the suffix of "whatever bar is when we print it", `bar` is evaluated *immediately* and the string is "foo" + "whatever bar is right now."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is happening because you are creating `jointRemapList` outside of your `sideList` loop. You want the list to be created dynamically by `sideLong` and `sideShort`, so you need to recreate it on each increment of your loop. Like the following:

```
side = ""
sideLong = ""
sideShort = ""
sideList = ["Right", "Left"]

for side in sideList:
    sideLong = side
    sideShort = side[0]

    jointRemapList =[
        ["Char_Hips", "Root_M"],
        ["Char_" + sideLong + "Finger1", "IndexFinger1_" + sideShort],
        ["Char_" + sideLong + "Finger2", "IndexFinger2_" + sideShort]
        ]

    for jointPair in jointRemapList:

        print sideLong, sideShort, jointPair
```

Comment: I agree this is the better solution, though it's going to be a bit slower than the `str.format` approach of Jared's.

Answer (score 3):

So the issue is that you are creating the strings when `jointRemapList` is created, and updates to `sideLong` and `sideShort` are not going to be reflected in those strings because *strings are immuatable*. Try using string formatting instead.

```
from itertools import product

joint_remap_list = [
    ["Char_Hips", "Root_M"],
    ["Char_{side}Finger1", "IndexFinger1_{abbrev}"],
    ["Char_{side}Finger2", "IndexFinger2_{abbrev}"]
]

sides = ["Left", "Right"]

for side, pair in product(sides, joint_remap_list):
    abbrev = side[0]
    formatted = [s.format(side=side, abbrev=abbrev) for s in pair]
    print side, abbrev, formatted
```

Comment: consider defining the formatted list on a separate line. `fmtd_joint_pair = [s.format(long=sideLong, short=sideShort) for s in jointPair]; print sideLong, sideShort, fmtd_join_pair` feels nicer to me.